# Transforming daily simple returns into weekly

Tags: time-series, data, r

I am trying to transform **daily simple returns** into **weekly returns**. I am using the following R code:

```
library(zoo)
tt <- seq(Sys.Date(), by='day', length=365)
vals <- data.frame(A=runif(365), B=rnorm(365), C=1:365)
z <- zoo(vals, tt)
week <- function(x)format(x, '%Y.%W')
dailytoweekly <- function(x) (prod(x+1)-1)
aggregate(z, by=week, FUN=dailytoweekly)
```

based on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16442396/convert-daily-to-weekly-monthly-data-with-r .
The function `dailytoweekly` is written on the basis of simple return's time-additive properties. What puzzles me is the result:

> ```
> 2015.50 19.7687016 -0.88561787 5.039000e+03
> 2015.51 19.8390703 -1.21981217 1.729728e+07
> 2015.52  4.9931289 -1.76381705 7.343900e+04
> 2016.00  2.2251422  2.98725821 7.979000e+03
> 2016.01 15.9745238 -1.33997280 5.967562e+09
> 2016.02 15.3588303 -0.91805535 3.389158e+10
> ```

Why there is a week 0 in the results and what is it supposed to represent? As there are 53 weeks in total, with indices from 0 to 52 inclusive. Any help on this issue would be appreciated :)

Comment: 0th week is just first week. Instead of your expected week labels from 1 to 53, R's function `format()` converts week indices to 0-52 range. Out of curiosity, why don't you use a readily available `to.weekly()` function from `xts` package?

Comment: @bushmanov Now i noticed there are also years where instead of 0-52 indices there are 1-53. But I hope this is exactly the same. I tried using it, however, when inputting an univariate xts object into 'to.weekly()' the function returned an OHLC structure as a result and I did not know how to work make it return a univariate object.

Comment: @bushmanov: `xts::to.weekly` wouldn't work (as the OP noted in their comment), but `xts::apply.weekly` would.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich I bet it would had he used it properly

Comment: @bushmanov: I'll bet you anything it wouldn't. They have daily returns. `to.weekly` will return the first, highest, lowest, and last return of each week. It won't sum them. Regardless, if you happen to be able to make it work somehow, I can always change the function and push to CRAN in order to win the bet. ;)

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Thanks for the offer ))). Resampling the data to weekly period with `to.weekly()` and then finding returns on that data is what I meant. I thought that was obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why there is a week 0 in the results and what is it supposed to represent?

The answer is found in `?strptime`:

> '%W' Week of the year as decimal number (00-53) using Monday as
>        the first day of week (and typically with the first Monday of
>        the year as day 1 of week 1).  The UK convention.

Perhaps you were expecting the output from one of the other formats?

> '%U' Week of the year as decimal number (00-53) using Sunday as
>        the first day 1 of the week (and typically with the first
>        Sunday of the year as day 1 of week 1).  The US convention.
>
> '%V' Week of the year as decimal number (01-53) as defined in ISO
>        8601.  If the week (starting on Monday) containing 1 January
>        has four or more days in the new year, then it is considered
>        week 1.  Otherwise, it is the last week of the previous year,
>        and the next week is week 1.  (Accepted but ignored on
>        input.)

---

You might try see if `xts::apply.weekly` solves your problem. Using it will avoid the problem in your question.